# How can a mongodb client save the operation id sent to database to kill it afterwards

Tags: mongodb, client, kill

I want to cancel an operation sent to mongodb:

I've tried to add a $comment in the query and get with:

```
db.currentOp({"query.filter.$comment" : "127.0.0.1"})
```

Example of currentOp output:

```
(...)
"query" : {
    "find" : "collectionName",
    "filter" : {
        "$comment" : "127.0.0.1",
        "field1" : "example of field1 value"
    }
(...)
```

But if the query is too large, with many fields or big strings, the mongo db.currentOp() command don't work.

```
"query" : {
            "$msg" : "query not recording (too large)"
          }
```

I know that slow queries can be canceled, but what i want to do is to kill operations did by an user, but i need to save in client side the opids sent to mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

stumbled upon your question as I'm trying to figure out the same thing. After some research, it seems that it's basically impossible to do easily.

Taking a look at the [Wire Protocol](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol/), you can see that when executing a query the only response the client will get is a `OP_REPLY`. However, this does not contain the `opId` (and is also only sent after processing).

The fields contained in `OP_REPLY` do include the standard message header which has a `responseTo` property. The value of this property is set to the `requestID` value which the client originally sent to the server. As this value is up to the client to generate (the NodeJS driver uses just an incrementing integer) it is *different* from the `opId` you are looking for.

The only way it seems to be possible to identify the `opId` for a query you executed might be to do some correlation using the output of [`$currentOp`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/currentOp/#pipe._S_currentOp).